# Можно ли таким образом обратиться к button?

Tags: html, python, django

Можно ли так обратиться к определенной кнопке на странице HTML и продиктовать ей определенные действия?

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('abc'):
           ......

        if request.POST.get('bbc'):
           .....
```

html

```
<form action="{% url 'new_channel' %}" method = "post">
 {% csrf_token %}
<button name="abc" type="submit"></button>
 .......
<button name="bbc" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нет, кнопка находится на стороне клиента (браузера), а код в `views.py` на стороне сервера. Нужно что-то сложнее и хитрее, чтобы с сервера сделать что-то на клиенте, например -- вебсокеты

Comment: Вы таким образом вытянете только текст в теге `<button>Текст_кнопки</button>`

Comment: а почему у меня все работало до обращения к конкретной кнопке? Т.е. без вот этой строчки if request.POST.get('abc'): все работает...

Comment: @Ekzotika 007 Всё работало - это что? Добавьте в вопрос больше информации о целях и задачах вашего кода, а также сам код.

Comment: Вы не подскажете мне как можно было бы обратиться к конкретной кнопке?

Comment: @Ekzotika 007 Спрошу ещё раз:) Что вы понимаете под "обратиться к кнопке"? Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @AlioshcaZзапрос при нажатии на определенную кнопку запрос к базе данных

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью ajax. создаём наш ajax, который будет отсылает запрос на сервер по указанному URL при нажатии на кнопку( class="mybutton") и получать от него ответ в success: function(data){...}, ответ будет виден в консоли браузера.

```
let data = {}

$('.mybutton').on('click', function(e){
    data['action'] = 'some_result';
    SendAjax();
});


function SendAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url_обработчика_функции ',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cached: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
  }
})
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse


class MyAction(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
            data = {}

            # Получаем данные из запроса
            action = self.request.POST.get('action')

            # Проверяем что значение соответствует ожидаемому
            # и возвращаем значение(в данном случае 1)
            if action == 'some_result':
                data['result'] = 1
            else:
                data['result'] = 'Error'
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

ну и сама кнопка

```
<input type="submit" class="mybutton" value="получить что-то">
```

так же со второй кнопкой. Потом результат выводить на страницу